Tag purpose: hash-collision
hash - Lots of entries, lots of obvious purposes
hash-collision - 78 at time of writing
collision-resistance - 21
hash-collision∩collision-resistance - 6

Not quite sure where, but somewhere on that list we seem to have a spare tag?
Personally I think collision-resistance is a better tag than "hash-collision", so my actual recommendation would be:
Tag Synonym Suggestion:
collision-resistance ← hash-collision

Certainly makes sense to me… “collision-resistance” seems to be a bit more on-point.

I agree, but would suggest going over the [tag:hash-collision] questions before the merge. There's quite a few questions there that aren't really about collision resistance in any meaningful sense, despite what the tag wiki says (like these questions which I just retagged).

Have to say I disagree with you @IlmariKaronen: I don't think they need a look before the merge, rather than every tag could do with being 'moderated' every now and then to keep things on track. My point is, the mistagged question are nothing to do with this tag rename, just a general theme with Crypto.SE

I sort of agree with you, but, just looking at the question list, [tag:hash-collision] looks a lot messier than [tag:collision-resistance]. I'm not saying that we should delay the merge for the sake of cleanup (at least not very long), just that it would be easier to do the cleanup now than after the merge.

Anyway, I just suggested the tag synonym; we have just enough users with 5+ answer score for [tag:collision-resistance] that we might be able to create it without mod assistance. AFAIK, that'd be a first for this site. (Also, AIUI, community-created tag synonyms don't automatically retag old questions, so if we do it that way, we'd have plenty of time for the cleanup.)

Are you sure? I was pretty confident that it would retag for us?
